Locust testing of flask app that uses redis has different results in local and production (Heroku)
I'm fairly new to using Redis. I'm developing a Python, Flask API that uses Redis. I wanted to test the API with Locust locally. I was curious to see how it differs from Heroku. Testing Heroku hosted API with Locust works fine and only creates a few connections (~5). But when I try to test locally, every request from Locust is a new connection. What is happening here? Is this expected? Do Heroku sends Redis request differently, if so, how? I'm curious to understand the difference.
Note: I also tried running through gunicorn and waitress locally.
Local results (gunicorn):



Type
Name
# reqs
# fails
Avg
Min
Max
Med
req/s
failures/s




GET
/data
377
304
(80.64%)
825
299
2645
840
5.91


POST
/submit
1048
988
(94.27%)
817
162
2562
840
16.44


-----
------------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------


Total
Aggregated
1425
1292
(90.67%)
819
162
2645
840
22.36



Heroku Results:



Type
Name
# reqs
# fails
Avg
Min
Max
Med
req/s
failures/s




GET
/data
8492
0
(0.00%)
1236
143
8100
960
35.44


POST
/submit
25371
13716
(54.06%)
560
140
2609
420
105.87


-----
------------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------


Total
Aggregated
33863
13716
(40.50%)
729
140
8100
510
141.31



Note: Heroku fails on submit is not zero because I forget to disable the request limit
